# How to save formatted text from google sheet cells to .rtf with Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, rtf

[image: Tab "Newsticker" in Google Spreadsheet]

I have a simple script in Google App Script, which takes string-values from cells in a google sheet (RSS-Feeds) and saves (updates) some .rtf - Documents. After some sync-processes and macro-helpers, those texts are displayed on a scrolling LED-bar, which can be updated through WIFI.

This works but I didn't manage to format the texts in the .rtf - Documents.

I experimented with the RichTextValueBuilder, which works fine to add formatting to text in a google spreadsheet but wasn't successful for formatting text in the .rtf's...
Another experiment was with html-tags. This brought the desired formatting-effect in the rtf-file but the application for the led-bar couldn't handle it.

Does anybody know how to help a noob in this situation? Thanks a lot in advance!

```js
function dataLED() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ass = ss.getSheetByName("Newsticker");

//VALUES FROM CELLS IN GOOGLE SHEETS
  var valuesLedBar = ass.getRange(2, 10, 4, 1).getValues();
  var vak1 = valuesLedBar[0];
  var vak2 = valuesLedBar[1];
  var vak3 = valuesLedBar[2];
  var vak4 = valuesLedBar[3]; 
  var marge = ass.getRange("B16").getValue();

//SAVE IN .RTF-FILES (IN FOLDER dataLEDbar)
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("dataLEDbar");
  
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();

    saveData(folder, "0808003135589.rtf", vak1);
    saveData(folder, "0808003133343.rtf", vak2);
    saveData(folder, "0808003136619.rtf", vak3);
    saveData(folder, "0808003135964.rtf", vak4);
    saveData(folder, "0808182631849.rtf", "Gewinnmarge diesen Monat:" + marge);
  }
  else {null}

};


//-------------------------------------------------SAVE

function saveData(folder, fileName, contents) {

  var children = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  var file = null;
  if (children.hasNext()) {
    file = children.next();
    file.setContent(contents);
  } else {
    file = folder.createFile(fileName, contents);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information? Also, where does the formatting information must come from? Does it have to come from a `RichTextValue`, or you just built that because you thought it would be a useful step before formatting the `rtf` file?

Comment: Thanks for your very quick comment. Sure, I can add a copy. The formatting information could come from the spreadsheet but it could also be generated in googleAppScript. It was built with RichTextValue since I thought it could make sense and because I wanted to have kind of a rainbow-effect, which is absolutely not necessary. :-)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a specific reason for using `rtf`? Wouldn't a regular Google Doc be appropriate? RTF files cannot be modified by DocumentApp, which is the proper service for formatting Google Docs. A Doc copy of the `rtf` could be made and formatted, and then an `rtf` copy of the formatted Doc could be made, but this would make the process more complex. So my question is, do you need to use `rtf`, or just formatting a normal Doc would be appropriate?

Comment: yeah, unfortunately the software for my LED scrolling bar is only accepting rtf - files... :-(

Comment: You need to create a rtf maker from scratch. The rules don't seem hard. But it needs significant effort to get all bold from doc and parse it to rtf

Comment: Thanks for your comment too! Hmm... I would never have expected my beloved LED-bar to cause that much work. What if the formatting information was already present in the rtf-file? Wouldn't it be possible to just append the text instead of overwriting the formatting information as I do it now?

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? You have a Google Spreadsheet which has the rich text in the cells "J2:J5". You want to retrieve the rich texts from the cells, and want to create them as a file with the mimeType of `application/rtf`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right for J2 - the other cells are not formatted with the rich text builder. But you are right with all your other assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, only cell of "J2" has the rich text. You want to retrieve the rich text from the cell "J2" and want to create it as a rich text file. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: well, basically I just want to create (or better update) a rich text file for every cell (J2-J5), with formatted text inside. Like in the comments mentioned before, it should not be possible to modify a RTF-file with the proper services from Google App Script directly. The formatting can come from the google sheet, from the rich text builder in GAS or be even inside the rich text file already... that's how I somehow tried it in the answer. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expected, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my understanding:

- You have a Google Spreadsheet which has the rich text in the cells of "J2:J5".
- You want to retrieve the rich texts from the cells of "J2:J5", and want to create them as each file with the mimeType of `application/rtf`.

  - In your case, 4 rich text files are created.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this answer, in order to achieve your goal, I used a Google Apps Script library of [RichTextApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp).

### Usage:

#### 1. Install GAS library.

Please install the GAS library of RichTextApp. You can see how to install at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp#1-install-library).

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following sample script, and run `myFunction`. By this, when the folder is existing, 4 rich text files are created to the folder.

```
function myFunction() {
  const filenames = ["0808003135589.rtf", "0808003133343.rtf", "0808003136619.rtf", "0808003135964.rtf"];
  const folderName = "dataLEDbar";
  const sheetName = "Newsticker";

  const folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  for (let i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
    const range = sheet.getRange("J" + i);
    const doc = DocumentApp.create("tempDocument");
    const docId = doc.getId();
    RichTextApp.SpreadsheetToDocument({range: range, document: doc});
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=rtf&id=" + docId;
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
    folder.createFile(res.getBlob().setName(filenames[i - 2]));
    DriveApp.getFileById(docId).setTrashed(true);
  }
}
```

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your actual situation.

### Reference:

- [RichTextApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp#1-install-library)

Comment: It's just working like it should! That's amazing! I have been struggling with a solution for a long time. Thank you so much for your brilliant help! It's just unbelievable to finally have it working!

Comment: @hohoo1 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Also, in my experience, I had the situation like your question. So I had created it as the GAS library. I'm glad the library was also useful for your situation. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this is helping anybody but I found a possible workaround for the problem. Better solutions are welcome, as this looks ugly and will not work in every case...

The RTF-file is formatted beforehand and I just append the text from the google sheet instead of replacing the content and formatting of the RTF.

```
function appendText() {

//Search Params for File and Folder
var fileName = "testRtf.rtf";
var folderName = "dataLEDbar";
//New Text in .rtf
var content = "NEWTEXT";

// get list of folders with matching name
var folderList = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
if (folderList.hasNext()) {
    //folder
    var folder = folderList.next();

    // search for files with matching name
    var fileList = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);

    if (fileList.hasNext()) {
        //file
        var file = fileList.next();

        //get rtf-file as string from Blob      
        var rtfContent = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
        //split Blob 
        var splitBlob = rtfContent.split("\\");
        var lenSplitBlob = splitBlob.length;
        //and replace last array with new text
        splitBlob[lenSplitBlob - 1] = "cf2 " + content + "}";

        //new Blob
        var newBlob = splitBlob.toString().replace(/,/g, '\\');

        //append text to already formatted .rtf-File
        file.setContent(newBlob);

    } else {
        // file not found
        null
    }
}
```

}